# Linked List in C - inserting the name is crashing the program

Tags: c, linked-list

The code works for all the other options in the menu, but for inserting the name and displaying the names is an issue as it shows random characters if I don't do the strcpy... I am just confused where the logic goes wrong with this linked list. I would appreciate your help!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>



// Main function that displays menu
int main()
{
    int input;
    char user;
 while(1)
    {
        printf("\nMenu of Operations\n");
        printf("1. Insert\n");
        printf("2. Display\n");
        printf("3. Count\n");
        printf("4. Delete\n");
        printf("5. Exit\n");
        printf("/////////////////////////////////////\n\n");
        printf("Please enter the operation you would like: ");

        if(scanf("%d", &input) >= 0)
        {
            switch(input)
            {

                case 1:
                    printf("Enter the name to insert: ");
                    scanf("%s", &input);
                    insert(user);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if(head == NULL)
                    {
                        printf("List is Empty\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("Element(s) in the list are : ");
                    }
                    display(n);
                    break;

                default:
                    printf("Invalid option\n");
                    break;
            }
        }

        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TL;DR! Please try to narrow it down, or preferably try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. One way you can narrow it down is to run your program in a debugger to see where (in your code) the crash happens. Though one thing to look at is why you `scanf` for a string and write it into an `int*`. Or your use of uninitialized pointers.

Comment: By the way, does that program even compile? `typedef struct person` what? Passing wrong type of arguments to function? Are you sure this is your actual program?

Comment: start from `char user[50];`... `scanf("%49s", user);insert(user);`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in `case 1`, where you're passing `&input` instead of `&user`. But that won't help you much.

`user` is a single `char`, but you'd be giving it to `scanf()` as if it was a character array. Change it to `char user[N]`, where `N` is larger than the maximum length that you expect (probably 50, as in `person`).

You will then need to change most of the other functions to take a `const char*` instead of a `char`. This will also fix the calls to `strcpy()`, which won't compile as they are right now because they expect the second argument to be a `const char*`.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it. I didn't see the error in case 1